# Python Convert all JPGS in a folder to PDF

Tags: python, pdf

I have code that converts all .jpgs in a folder to one PDF, but it is not working.  I believe it to be because of something with my directory being passed.  The below is the code and my output.  Now it states that my PDF was written, but it doesn't display the directory.

```
root = "C:\\Users\\Matthew\\Desktop\\Comics\\" 

try:
   n = 0
   for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
    PdfOutputFileName = os.path.basename(dirpath) + ".pdf" 
    c = canvas.Canvas(PdfOutputFileName)
    if n > 0 :
        for filename in filenames:
            LowerCaseFileName = filename.lower()
            if LowerCaseFileName.endswith(".jpg"):
                    print(filename)
                    filepath    = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    print(filepath)
                    im          = ImageReader(filepath)
                    imagesize   = im.getSize()
                    c.setPageSize(imagesize)
                    c.drawImage(filepath,0,0)
                    c.showPage()
                    c.save()
    n = n + 1
    print "PDF of Image directory created" + PdfOutputFileName

except:
     print "Failed creating PDF"
```

The below is my output:

```
PDF of Image directory created.pdf
```

Comment: You [should be using](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) 4 spaces (and only 4 spaces) for indentation, and using it consistently. The code you posted uses 3, 1, 4, and 8 spaces at various points (in addition to the first line being incorrectly indented), making it very difficult to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At start `n` is `0`.

The `os.walk` loop only runs once in this case (since there's probably only one directory to scan, and you get only one `print` statement so that's the proof), providing `filenames` and `dirnames` as iterables, but you skip the iteration by testing `n > 0`, so it does nothing.

```
   for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
    PdfOutputFileName = os.path.basename(dirpath) + ".pdf" 
    c = canvas.Canvas(PdfOutputFileName)
    if n > 0 :
```

My advice: get rid of the `if n > 0` test.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I changed the n variable and the loop now works, but I am still seeing 'PDF of Image directory created.pdf' being printed out with no pdf in the directory I specified.

Comment: can you just `print` the filenames, see if there really are .jpg files in them?

Comment: I am printing both the file name and the file path in the loop.

Comment: So i created a directory in my Comics folder called FlashComics.  I now get outpout which is expected but still no PDF was created. output: PDF of Image directory createdFlashComics.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  After further research i noticed the PDF was actually being saved in the Project itself not the directory of the imgs.  You have answered my original question.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `img2pdf` for lossless conversion in Python:

https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf

Example CLI usage:

```
img2pdf img1.png img2.jpg -o out.pdf
```